# Mac mini won't restart after erasure with Find My app

Tags: hard-drive, startup, mac-mini

I recently had to erase my Mac mini (bought in 2019) using the Find My app on my iPhone.

After I did, I switched on the Mac mini and tried to install macOS. However, when prompted to choose a start-up disk, no disk was available.

There seemed to be no way out of it, so I turned the Mac off and back on and since then it displays nothing on the screen: no flashing folder with a question mark, no startup menu, nothing.

I have tried the following steps (from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-mide/HT201255)) (with an Apple keyboard plugged in):

- Leaving the Mac unplugged for 24h hours and trying again
- Booting with Cmd R
- Booting with Option
- Booting with Option Cmd P R
- Booting with Shift
- Booting with D
- Booting with Option D (Ethernet cable connected)

None of this showed anything in the monitor (it just goes to sleep mode after a while) except for Option-Cmd-P-R (resetting the NVRAM) which showed the Apple logo and then the flashing folder with the question mark.

This is driving me crazy since I just erased the Mac using Apple's app and now Apple wants to charge me for a repair.

Can anyone suggest anything else I can try before sending it for repair?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac? If yes you could try to boot into target disk mode and see if your other Mac can access the drive and maybe repair it. You could further try to make a USB installer disk or even a bootable usb drive

Comment: I do. I downloaded big sur onto an external drive and tried to start the Mac mini with it plugged in but it still didn’t show anything on the screen...

Comment: Did you create a bootable drive? Or did you create a installer? Also, just to be sure, you pressed `cmd` + `option` while booting and while the drive was plugged in, nothing showed up? Can you try a different cable and monitor? Are you sure the MacMini port is working? Do you know if something like VNC or SMB is enabled, so you could try to login from your other device?

Comment: I downloaded the OS and moved into a hard drive I have (it's there along with other files). And I did press cmd + option and nothing showed up. The cable and the monitor work with other Macs, I have tried that. Not sure about the VNC and SMB (don't know what those are). I haven't had a laptop to google this better so will google all this stuff now!

Comment: downloading the OS and moving it to a hard drive doesn't sound to me like either of the options mentioned above: USB installer: https://www.macworld.com/article/3566910/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-big-sur-installer-drive.html. You will need to do this on a free hard drive or USB pen drive. VNC allows you to access the Macs graphical user interface in the local network, provided it connects to it and is enabled. SMB allows you to access the hard drive similar to a folder, but also over the local network.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I now followed all the steps outlined in the article. However, when I get to the instruction **Power up (or restart) your Mac. Press down on the Option key while the Mac boots.** I hit a dead end again because nothing shows up on the screen... Any ideas?

Comment: @mcansado did you disable the T2 security chip's feature which prevents you from booting from another disk before you erased your Mac? If not, I'm afraid you've bricked it, and must go to an Apple store and get the logic board replaced. That's what I had to do.

Comment: You're a hero, this worked! After my last comment, I reset the NVRAM again and eventually the Mac started its normal path (prompting for a WiFi network, installing the OS, etc). Thanks so much, saved me 100 bucks 